# Arduino array and button state not working when new array introduced

Tags: c++, arduino

I am working on a home light project and have it working, in a simple fashion so one switch controls multiple lights.

I have introduced another array that checks previous state, if there is no change then it doesn't drop into the routine that turns the light on or off.  I have two reasons for doing this, first at the moment the routine is constantly pulling the pin high.  The second and more import reason, I have created another project that controls the lights via a webpage.  I would like to combine the switches and web control into one project.  If I have the switches saying off constantly and the web saying on it will cause me problems.

With the previous state array introduced switches control the wrong light or not at all and it seems to be in a random state.

```
const int zone2[] = {8,13,0};
const int zone3[] = {11,0};
const int zone4[] = {7,0};
const int zone5[] = {9,0};
const int zone6[] = {12,0};

const int * zones[]={zone2,zone3,zone4,zone5,zone6};

int buttonState[] = {0,0};         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

int previousState[]={0,0,0,0,0};    // array for holding the previous state

void setup() 
{
 //initialize the output pins that will control lights
 pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(9,OUTPUT);

 // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
 //set all light switches to the same block ie pins 30 - 36

 byte i; 

 //this loop sets all the pins as inputs 
 for (i=30;i< 36;i++) {
   pinMode(i, INPUT);  
   digitalWrite(i,HIGH);  // this makes it connect to the internal   resistor
   }
 }

void loop()
{
 // read the state of the pushbutton value:
 byte myInput =2; //?? is this needed??  don't thinks so

 // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
 // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:  


int ArrayCount;

int arrayPosition;
for (int z = 0; z < 5; ++z) 
  {
    buttonState[z] = digitalRead(z+30); 
for (arrayPosition = 0;zones[z][arrayPosition] ; arrayPosition++)
      {
        if ((buttonState[z] == HIGH) && (previousState[z] == 0 ))
          // turn LED on:    
          digitalWrite(zones[z][arrayPosition],HIGH); 
          previousState[z] = 1;//I have added this line to handle previous state
          } 
        else if ((buttonState[z] == LOW) && (previousState[z] == 1)) {
        // turn LED off;
          digitalWrite(zones[z][arrayPosition],LOW);
          previousState[z] = 0;//I have added this line to handle previous state
          }
      } 
  }

}
```

Comment: You at least seem to be doing out-of-bounds accesses to `buttonState[]` (z is 0..4 and used to index a two element array) probably should fix that first.

Comment: Hi Thanks could you please explain further I don't understand.

Comment: the array `buttonState` has two elements you try to read the third, the forth  , etc...